# Need to divide variable DC signal voltage

Tags: voltage-divider

I have a CNC controller that outputs 0-10v PWM signal voltage for the purpose of controlling cutting spindle RPM (or in this case, laser power output). This is not the actual driving voltage, this is a signal voltage (I hope that makes sense).
My laser engraver requires 0-5v PWM signal, so I essentially need to cut the controller's output voltage by 50%.

I am not an electronics expert by any means, but I can successfully put a circuit together. I have op amps, resistors, capacitors, and diodes at my disposal, so hopefully it can be done with what I have on-hand.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: No, I don't have that information. I could probably get it from the manufacturer though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you apparently just want to divide a signal voltage in two and have no current requirement:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkoi8I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is called a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider).

Comment: Answer could be improved if you refer to issues in this solution taken into account outgoing impedance and the advantages of add a op amp or more improved voltage dividers.

Comment: Indeed. I was half expecting the question to be closed as there are numerous other questions, even recently, that are essentially the same.

Comment: I did actually search first, and found voltage dividers, but they seemed to be @ dedicated input voltage. I wasn't sure if this would be the best method, being a variable source voltage.

Comment: add a voltage follower op amp to the divider circuit so that the output voltage does not change as a result of the impedance of the circuit connected to the divider circuit.